# Question about certain operation

Tags: complex-numbers

I am not sure about this, but if I have a "vector" with complex entries such as
\begin{equation}
A=(a_1+ia_2,a_3+ia_4,a_5+ia_6)
\end{equation}
How do we define $Im\{A\}$?

Comment: $ \Im (A) = (a_2,a_4,a_6)$

Comment: Is there any bibliography where you took this definition?